# How to Create Desktop Shortcut with requestShortcut()?

Tags: java, jar

Can someone explain/show me how to use `requestShortcut` method in this [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html#requestShortcut%28boolean,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String%29), I want to make my jar a desktop shortcut while program was running.

Below is my Java code

```
private static Component frame;

  public static void main(String[] args){

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "Hello World", "Hello World",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

   //I want to create shortcut code here

  requestShortcut(true, false, ""); // return cannot find symbol
                                    // this method should create desktop
                                    // shortcut if i understand it right.
}
```

How do we actually implement this [requestShortcut()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html#requestShortcut%28boolean,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String%29) method?

P/s : The purpose I want to create shortcut because I will move the shortcut to path all program/startup.

Comment: I think maybe this method was not build for java application, but ill wait for other to review and comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think requestShortcut() cannot be used by java application